# What is the actual meaning of 'tuppenuth'?

Tags: meaning

What is the actual meaning of 'tuppenuth'? I saw someone using this word in a discussion like this:

> My tuppenuth: <list of his/her thoughts>

I googled it already, and it suggests new words/similar words.
Is it a short form of some other word?

Comment: Could you put the word in context?

Comment: I found enough uses of the word via Google to extrapolate a meaning and origin, but I can't find an official source anywhere.

Comment: "Tuppenuth" *per se* is not a word.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone declared that a perfectly cromulent word "isn't a word" ...

Comment: @JamesRandom, no, but you can have this tuppenuth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to hazard an attempt at it's meaning, notwithstanding you didn't provide a sentence or context.

There is the word "tuppence".

> tuppence
>  n. Chiefly British
>  Variant of twopence.
>  [American
>   Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tuppence)

And there are the terms twopenn'orth and two pennorth:

> twopenn'orth
>   1. An amount of something that is worth or costs twopence.
>  [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/twopenn%27orth)

Or a tuppence worth.

I'm guessing it's a variant spelling of "twopenn'orth", meaning "tuppence worth" or "two pennies' worth". The pronunciation given for "twopenn'orth" at Oxford Living Dictionaries is tuːˈpɛnəθ, or (too-PEN-eth), the final 'e' in "eth" being a schwa sound. And this is the pronunciation it seems to me from the look of "tuppenuth". Again, check the link to hear the pronunciation.

Does that fit the usage of the word as you saw it?

Comment: I saw someone using this word in a discussion like below, 
"My tuppenuth: <list of his/her thoughts> "
Thanks, this answers my question.

Comment: @Subala Then it just seems like an attempt at a phonetic spelling of twopenn'orth. If I had only 'heard' the term and not seen it spelled before, I'd probably guess the same way.

Comment: Yeah, my guess would be "two pennies worth" -- basically, saying the equivalent to the US "Here's my two cents' worth".

Comment: That matches what I was seeing. I also saw it spelled once as "tuppen'uth," which follows the "twopenn'orth" idea.